# Show .tiff with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tiff

I am trying to build a GUI to show some .tiff images. I have the following code. I works with .png and all formats except with .tiff. When I open a .tiff images it is shown as white in the GUI. Anyone knows what is the command to show .tiff?
This is my code:

```
root= Tk()
root.title('My first GUI')
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)      
canvas.pack()     
def open():
    global my_image
    
    root.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Users/gabrielasanchezzz/Desktop/Samples", title="Hola", filetypes=(("All files","*.*"),("tiff","*.tiff")))
    my_label=Label(root, text= root.filename).pack()
    my_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    my_image_label=Label(image=my_image).pack()

my_btn=Button(root, text="Open File", command=open).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is what I get:
[image]
Thanks!!

Comment: remove `my_image=Image.open(root.filename)` and it should work fine. Also, be careful when you add a label in a function like that, with your current code you will be creating a new label each time you press the button, without destroying the previous Label.

Comment: Hi, I did that but get the white screen I attached. Any other idea? It works for .png files and jpeg, just not for .tiff

Comment: can you check your image? maybe it's just white. Try with some other images.

Comment: The image is fine, if I display it with display in the notebook it is shown fine

Answer (score 0):

Check how you import tkinter and PIL as python can mistake `PIL.image` as `tkinter.image`.

The following works for me:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, Label
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.title('My first GUI')
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)      
canvas.pack()     
def open():
    global my_image
    
    root.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Users/gabrielasanchezzz/Desktop/Samples", title="Hola", filetypes=(("All files","*.*"),("tiff","*.tiff")))
    my_label=Label(root, text= root.filename).pack()
    my_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    my_image_label=Label(image=my_image).pack()

my_btn=Button(root, text="Open File", command=open).pack()

root.mainloop()
```